# How to import excel files into SqlDatabase .mdf file

Tags: sql, database, excel

I have one long excel sheet with books details of a library..can i import this data into a .mdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need SQL Server Management Studio, and use its Import feature

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Depends on SQL Server version you have installed (for exact instructions) but you use DTS (Data Transformation Services).

Right click on your database and you should see **Import data**. Wizard will do most of the work, basically it's a next next next operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step-by-step guide from the horse's mouth: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686